# HTML/Django tags appear out of nowhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I have a strange behavior on my html page. I use Django and in my template I have this code:

```
<div id="article">
    {{ post.body|safe|truncate }}<a href="/article/{{post.slug}}.html" id="readmore">Read more</a>
</div>
<div id="tag">
    {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
        <a href="/tag/{{ tag.slug }}"><p>{{ tag.name|tag }}</p></a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

and it returns something of this style:

```
<div id="article">
    <p>
        <i><u>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...
            <a href="#" id="Readmore">Read more</a>
        </u></i>
    </p>
</div>

<i><u>
    <div id="tag">
        <a href="/tag/lorem"><p>#lorem</p></a>
        <a href="/tag/nous"><p>#ipsum</p></a>
        <a href="/tag/quand"><p>#dolor</p></a>
        <a href="/tag/tiens"><p>#sit</p></a>
        <a href="/tag/tu"><p>#amet</p></a>
    </div>
</u></i>
```

There are tag `<i>` and `<u>` which are added and I do not really understand why. Tags are not yet in the same div than article. I do not see why they have inherited from the`<i>` and `<u>` of the div Article.
I would like an explanation if possible please and how I can fix that.

Comment: Maybe those tags are in post.body? Since you mark it as safe, they are rendered as is.

Comment: yeah it's normal they are rendered as is for the div article but why others tags i and u are added in the html at the div tags?

Comment: Your template must be going through some other preprocessor that adds <i> and <u> tags. I can't really see what's wrong with your code. You should look somewhere else in your app.

Comment: I just tried something by removing the safe it removes tags <i> and <u> of the div tag but doesn't display the article in italics and underlined anymore. How can i fix it?

Comment: You should use css properties and change "article" and "tag" to classes. <i>  and <u> tags are not really used anymore and make it more chaotic as you can see.

Comment: yes indeed the tags are not applied to the post

Comment: I mean that using <i> and <u> tags is becoming an anti pattern. You should keep your presentation layer in .css files to separate it from content.

Comment: the problem is that I used as a text editor, medium-editorjs https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor and when he backup the item in the database, it saves the tags in. So to display text with the correct rendering I used the safe filter of django for it takes into account tags.

Comment: You should strip the tags (or leave the desired ones) before saving text to the database. It can be a major security risk if you leave for example <script> tags.

Comment: ok but if I do it when he takes the data in the database for rendering it i have to do it manually with css...? For the <script> tags i have the filter removetags for deleting it.

Comment: If it's a user input from an in-browser editor, it's easier to use <i> and <u> tags than css, but that's a special case for using tags like <i> and <u>.

Comment: There is only me who can normally get articles. So with my editor, medium-editor, it does not matter that it saves the tags as well but the problem is after. I do not see how to solve the problem of tags <i> and <u> which are added at the tags <div> if I put a filter Safe but if I not put this filter it does not take them into account and it is ca I want to correct.